# What is the term used for a place name that represents something other than the place itself?

Tags: single-word-requests, ambiguity, figures-of-speech, toponyms

There is a special term for when a place name is representative of something other than the actual place itself but I can't remember what it is.

For example: 'Brussels' may be used to refer to the European Union or 'Washington' to refer to the U.S. political establishment.

Does anyone know what this term would be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a *metonym*.

> **metonym** *noun*
>   A word, name, or expression used as a substitute for something else with which it is closely associated. For example, Washington is a metonym for the US government.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/metonym)

Answer (score -1):

Also consider the word "synecdoche". It's when one thing is used to represent a whole/larger thing (for example, the crown = the monarchy).